# How to get the APS viewer property object of PropertyPanel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/propertypanel/#onpropertyclick-property-event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxnCm.png)

I see the "onPropertyClick(property,event)" function of Autodesk.Viewing.UI.PropertyPanel and I try to get the first inpuet data property of it .but I can see the function that return value is the property . How can I get and add event to it after I use this.addProperty() to create properties of it ?
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: You cannot add an event. Your `PropertyPanel` class simply has to implement a method called `onPropertyClick(prop, event)`. The `prop` argument will contain information about the specific property (category, name, value), and the `event` argument will contain the actual DOM event.